# Enum in PDA does not update, ever

Tags: solana-program, anchor-lang, program

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
#[repr(u8)]
pub enum Stage {
    Initiated, // user has paid
    Processing,
    Processed,
    Finished,
}

#[derive(
AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, PartialEq, Eq,Copy, Clone, Debug
)]
#[repr(u8)]
pub enum Status {
    Processing,
    Lost, // user has paid
    Won,
}

#[account(zero_copy)]
#[derive(
AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize
)]
pub struct House{
    pub bet_amount: u64,
    pub side: u8,
    pub hash: [u8; 32],
    pub vendor: Pubkey,
    pub player: Pubkey,
    pub client_seed: u64,
    pub server_seed: [u8; 32],
    pub result: u8,
    pub stage: Stage,
    pub status: Status,
}


impl Default for Stage {
    fn default() -> Stage {
        Stage::Initiated
    }
}
impl Default for Status {
    fn default() -> Status {
        Status::Processing
    }
}
```

The stage and status do not update no matter what. For other accounts it works, but this it does not. I've been busting my head over this for a few hours. I absolutely have no clue what the hell is going on...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet showing a way of storing PDAs in accounts. It might be better for your purposes.

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, AnchorDeserialize, AnchorSerialize)]
pub enum VoterType {
    Donator,
    Staker
}

impl VoterType {
    fn from(val: u8) -> std::result::Result<VoterType, Error> {
        match val {
            1 => Ok(VoterType::Donator),
            2 => Ok(VoterType::Staker),
            invalid_number => {
                msg!("Invalid voter type: {}", invalid_number);
                Err(ErrorCode::InvalidVoterType.into())
            }
        }
    }

    fn to_u8(&self) -> u8 {
        match self {
            VoterType::Donator => 1,
            VoterType::Staker => 2,
        }
    }
}
```

Implementing methods for conversion between my `VoterType` enum and a `u8` lets me store enum values in an account struct like this:

```
#[account]
pub struct NextRoundVoter {
    voting_power: u8,
    has_voted: bool,
    voter_type: u8,
    bump: u8
}
```

Here to store a `VoterType::Donator` in an account we do `VoterType::Donator.to_u8()` and assign our result `1` to voter_type.

The reverse also holds.

To contextualize a voter_type value we use `VoterType::from(voter_type)?`. A value of 1 gives us the expected result of `VoterType::Donator`.